# "NVM_E_INTEGRITY_FAILED" Error was detected at startup during "NVM_ReadAll"

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, rtos, eeprom, autosar

Due to CRC( Autosar)issue for a particular NvBlock, "NVM_E_INTEGRITY_FAILED" Error was observed during "NVM_ReadAll()".

I tried to debug but couldn't root cause the issue.

Out of all the blocks only one NvBlock has the crc issue and obviously causing the NNM_Readll to fail("NVM_REQ_NOT_OK").

Please suggest the best method to debug this issue.

Comment: This isn't possible to debug with a "generic MCU" in mind. Though to begin with, grab a hex dump of the memory segment with your debugger, then compare that with the linker-generated binary.

Comment: Usually, the NvM keeps the status per block internally to remember the current state of each block and its last request on, but this is implementation internal. You could try to check in the singleblock callbacks, if certain request failed per block.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lundin and Kesselhaus. Its seems the SPI dirver has the issue in reading the data from Eeprom for that particular block (block size greater than 1k). The calculated CRC has different value compared to actual CRC value. Thus NVM_Integrity Error is set.